# Which method should I use to compute optical flow ground truth?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm currently trying to compute some dense optical flow ground truth which will later be used to train a neural network. RGB, infrared and 6D-poses are available for each pair of frames.

I already had a look at the openCV library:

1. The Lucas-Kanade method only outputs a sparse optical flow, hence it is not
   usable in this scenario.
2. The Farneback method outputs a dense flow but only approximates the result. Further, it only relies on RGB data and ignores the depth information.

I found some code at a Github [project](https://github.com/liyi14/mx-DeepIM/blob/d375474ed4668b0b0b9a9260c069e3edfa55c7a0/lib/pair_matching/flow.py#L12:L81) which is almost what I need. For some reason, however, it truncates parts of the optical flow.

Is there any publically available method to use in this case?

Comment: What about FlowNet? https://github.com/ClementPinard/FlowNetPytorch

Comment: Since I want to create ground truth data to train an optical flow network, the data should be calculated given all the information available (i.e. RGB, infrared, 6D-pose and 3D model of the object). 

The Flownet only **approximates** the optical flow instead of calculating it algorithmically.

Comment: That was unclear in your original question. Now that makes sense. The truncation only happens in one line. Would it make sense for you to extract out this method and its dependencies and use this, removing that truncation?

Comment: Hi, are the methods mentioned in the question (Lucas-Kanade and Farneback) very expensive computationally? We cannot use them directly instead of training neural network?